# Escape Quotes in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, encoding, nsstring, escaping

I'm using this code snippet to encode characters to be friendly with a POST request:

```
   NSString *unescaped = [textField text];
   NSString *escapedString = (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
                                                                                  NULL,
                                                                                  (__bridge_retained CFStringRef)unescaped,
                                                                                  NULL,
                                                                                  (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                                                  kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
```

Which works great, but does not add escape Quotation marks: `"`

How do I escape Quotation marks in IOS?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I needed to take the user inputted NSString from `[textField text]` and make sure that if there are quotation marks in the string, they are escaped properly in order to send through a POST statement.

My solution was:

```
unescaped = [unescaped stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""];
```

Comment: why not use NSRegularExpression's "escapedPatternForString:" class method?

Answer (score 4):

First, you don't want to use `__bridge_retained` in your cast to a `CFStringRef`.  Just use `__bridge`.

Second, you don't have to escape the quotes manually by string replacement.  Just add the quote character to the set of characters to be quoted when calling `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes()`.  Like so:

```
NSString *unescaped = [textField text];
NSString *escapedString = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,
                                                                                    (__bridge CFStringRef)unescaped,
                                                                                    NULL,
                                                                                    CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]\""),
                                                                                    kCFStringEncodingUTF8));
```

(In addition to adding the quote to the set, I changed to use `CFBridgingRelease()` rather than a `__bridge_transfer` cast because I find it clearer. It satisfies the feeling that all CF "Create" functions need a corresponding "Release". Also, I changed the use of a `@""` literal cast to `CFStringRef` to just a `CFSTR("")` literal.)

Answer (score 3):

Quotes are to be escaped with `\"`.

As in:

```
(CFStringRef)@"I'm an \"example\""
```

Comment: I know this, I want you to know how to get a user inputted `"` and change it to: `\"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\"` instead of using `"` directly...

Special Characters like Quotes, slashes and others require `\` to make that character to remove its special functionality.