# JSON - How to allow spacial characters in JSON?

Tags: c#, .net, json

```
Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

System.IO.Stream inptStrm = Request.InputStream;

byte[] bytes = new byte[inptStrm.Length];

int i = inptStrm.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(inptStrm.Length));

string Input = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
JsonTextParser parsor = new JsonTextParser();

JsonObject jsonObj = parsor.Parse(Input);
```

### My input string is :::::

```
{
  "function":"addwhy",

  "lastname":"\"", // this line


}
```

My agent did also try to convert it to UTF8 format but,my code generated error when it goes for parsor.

Answer (score 1):

It should just be a backslash, as in...

```
"shopname":"\"\""
"lastname": "\"\"",
```

If you add this JSON...

```
{
    "function": "addwhy",
    "firstname": "firstname",
    "lastname": "\"\"",
    "dob": "8/8/2001",
    "dop": "testplace",
    "street": "teststreet",
    "nr": "testnr",
    "postcode": "123456",
    "place": "testplace",
    "telephone": "telephone",
    "incidentid": "1",
    "Aangehoudendoor": "testAangehoudendoor",
    "Waar": "testWaar",
    "DayTime": "Monday,
    6: 48PM",
    "createdby": "1",
    "updatedby": "0",
    "shopId": "1",
    "witneesid": "1",
    "op": "",
    "om": "testom"
}
```

..to the [JSONLint validator](http://jsonlint.com/), you'll see the validation is successful.

Comment: oh, as the question suggests...?

Comment: @ParinParikh why do you need to insert quotes in the database?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is coming in wrong. The client should escape the quotes before creating the JSON.

Use [`JSON.stringify`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031324/javascript-how-escape-quotes-in-a-var-to-pass-data-through-json) for JavaScript or follow  [Escape Quotes in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117031/escape-quotes-in-objective-c).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting error on parsing you should take care of quotes in response (i.e., avoid malformed JSON responses). Try taking quotes as:

```
  ....
  ....
  "lastname":"""", 
  "dob":"8/8/2001",
  "dop":"testplace",
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: and what is the error ?