# Objective-C equivalent function of mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: objective-c, ios7

is there an Equivalent function of `mysql_real_escape_string()` in *Objective-C*?

I'm trying to insert a string with an allowed characters ('") to a db.

Comment: iOS has built-in SQLite3 support, I suppose you can thus use the SQLite3 C API. In this case, use prepared statements and `sqlite3_bind_text()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` with the right params.

See [Escape Quotes in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117031/escape-quotes-in-objective-c)